# Is there a way to extract a specific part of a filename in Python to loop over it?

Tags: python, date, for-loop, format, filenames

The format of all of my files are as so...

`['PC-PC02@2019-01-18-00-00-00.mseed', 'PC-PC01@2019-01-19-00-00-00.mseed', 'PC-PC02@2019-01-19-00-00-00.mseed', 'PC-PC01@2019-01-20-00-00-00.mseed', 'PC-PC02@2019-01-20-00-00-00.mseed']`

(I will have a lot more files with a lot more days once I get this running, but just getting the code to work on a few, and I cannot change the format of my files).

I need to be able to import files for an entire month, but can only run the code for one day at a time, say 2019-01-18, run the entire code, and then move on to 2019-01-19 and so on.

**Is there any way to extract just the day of the month from the file, and then loop over one day at a time?**

To reiterate, I need to be able to import a months worth of files, but I want to run my code on day 18, then day 19, then day 20 and so. I am also open to any other suggestions that may work. I have tried googling and many other things to try to get this, but none of it seems to work, I am still learning Python too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) function and specify @ as separator.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string manipulation tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are getting these in order from a location or some process is creating these files in order you can list out all the file objects in the directory and sort them according to their created time and then process them one by one.